# Is it against rules of admob placing two ads on one app activity?

Tags: android, admob

Is it against rules of admob placing two ads on one app activity?

The publisher IDs would be equivalent.

If that is against the rules, could you put two ads on one activity but with different publisher IDs?

On Android

Comment: IANAL, what does the user agreement say? or any other contract you agreed to before participating?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the AdMob help page [Tips for Developers & Publishers](http://helpcenter.admob.com/content/policies-tips-developers-publishers)

> The number of ads on a single page should not exceed one if the ad is
>   fixed to the screen top or screen bottom. If the page scrolls, there
>   should be a maximum of one ad on the top and one ad on the bottom, and
>   both ads should not appear on the same page.

Comment: The link seems to be broken !! any update on this !?!